# Porque se resetean mis datos de controles textbox cuando doy click en asp

Tags: html, c#, aspx

Tengo un website en asp de visual studio 2017, cuando doy click en botón de mostrar me resetea mis controles, como puedo detener eso?

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
Text="Mostrar" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"/></p>
```

En la parte **.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
filtros.Add(TipoProceso.TODOS.ToString()); 
filtros.Add(TipoProceso.MESA_DE_CORTE.ToString()); 
//etc,ect contenido_html += "<label>Seleccionar proceso: </label>"; 
contenido_html += string.Format("<select name=\"{0}\" id=\"{0}\" 
runat=\"server\">", "slcAgrupamiento"); 
foreach (var item in filtros) { 
contenido_html += string.Format("<option value=\"{0}\">{0}</option>",
item); 
} 
 contenido_html += "</select>"; 
}
```

Ya intente validando si es `postback` pero no es lo mas viable ya que al no recargar la pagina no carga los datos iniciales que tengo predeterminados  en combobox a través de consultas en el método page_load()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas inicializando datos en el `Page_Load` recuerda que debes ponerlo dentro del !IsPostBack, algo como ser

```
public void Page_Load(..)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       //aqui inicializas/cargas los controles
    }
}
```

El evento de cada control ingresa al evento `Page_Load` por lo que sino evaluas si es postback eliminaras su contenido

Comment: dejame hacer pruebas, pero no creo que funciona ya que no se cargaran nuevamente mis combobox

Comment: todos los eventos ya sea el cambio de seleccion de un combo o el click de un boton pasa por el Page_Load, por eso si asignas datos a controles en el Load debes ponerlo como indico dentro de la validacion del `if(!IsPostBack)`

Comment: pero cuando inicia por primera vez no cargan

Comment: no entiendo, que cosa no carga? podrias poner el codigo donde cargas los datos de los controles que dices se resetean

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  filtros.Add(TipoProceso.TODOS.ToString());
  filtros.Add(TipoProceso.MESA_DE_CORTE.ToString());  
//etc,ect

  contenido_html += "<label>Seleccionar proceso: </label>";
  contenido_html += string.Format("<select name=\"{0}\" id=\"{0}\" runat=\"server\">", "slcAgrupamiento");
  foreach (var item in filtros)
  {
   contenido_html += string.Format("<option value=\"{0}\">{0}</option>", item);
  }
  contenido_html += "</select>";
 }

Comment: Corrijo mi argumento, al iniciar por primera vez si cargar pero si le agrego el if(!IsPostBack) al momento de dar click o seleccionar el combobox pasa por esta validacion y al no entrar no carga mi comboxo, aparece vacio

Comment: No aparece con datos al no volverse a cargar con if(!IsPostBack), pero si no le pongo esta validacion si se vuelve a llenar el combobox pero anula la seleccion anterior

Comment: Si gustas y no esta muy ocupado te podria pasar el id de teamviewer, no se si eso esta en contra de las politicas

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el codigo con formato, como comentario no se entiende. No tengo tanto tiempo como para revisar codigo conectandome de forma remota

Comment: pero por lo que veo generas html dinamica concatenando string ,eso es una pesima idea, si quieres hacerlo de esa forma se usa ajax con jquery y webmethods, pero nunca d ela forma en que lo realizas. O sino usa el control DropDownList para definir el combo de asp.net

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo leandro, nada mas saco mis pendientes y me meto de lleno al modo que me recomiendas, por tu experiencia confio en que sera la mejor opcion